# Change cookie value in Express framework

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to update a cookie in Express framework. Inside app.js, I have the following code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var langCookie = req.cookies.lang;
    var currentLang = req.i18n.getLocale();
    if(langCookie === undefined){
        res.cookie('lang', currentLang , { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false },);
    }else if(langCookie !==  currentLang){
        // The following line doesn't work.
        //res.cookie('lang', currentLang , { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false });
        // Neither this line updates the value.
        req.cookies.lang = currentLang;
    }
    next();
});
```

How to update cookie value in Express?

Comment: `res.cookie('lang', currentLang , { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false });` should do the job, maybe currentLang is null.

Comment: @DiegoRBaquero Thanks. I see that I'm setting the cookie in request object instead of in response, this seems to be the problem. I'll check it later, if it fix the problem I'll be glad to mark your response as correct answer, in case you want to post it.